# Adding jQuery ContextMenu in Gridview

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

I have a menu right here.But where to add the menu in the script so that i can get the context menu in the grid.

// HTML

```
<ul id="myMenu" class="contextMenu">
        <li class="insert"><a href="#insert">Add New</a></li>
        <li class="edit"><a href="#edit">Edit</a></li>
        <li class="delete"><a href="#delete">Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
```

//Script

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".customerRow").contextMenu(function (action, el, pos) { contextMenuWork(action, el, pos); });
});
```

Comment: which plugin are you using? also add section of html for your grid

Comment: @Dreamwalker: jquery.contextMenu.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Adding the menu after the contextmenu in your your script.

Replace:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".customerRow").contextMenu(function (action, el, pos) { contextMenuWork(action, el, pos); });
});
```

With:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".customerRow").contextMenu({ menu: 'myMenu' }, function (action, el, pos) { contextMenuWork(action, el, pos); });
  });
```